# How can I import this formated txt file into a SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, import

I have txt files that are a output of one especific Software, that file always have the same format, see it below. The datas starts at line 31, in this example i put only a feel lines of the TXT file, I can not change this format due to it is the output of one software. I need to import this file into a Table in SQL Server. How do I do it?

```
 RECORDED_YEAR                  Col:     1 -     4 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 RECORDED_DAY                   Col:     5 -     8 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 RECORDED_HOUR                  Col:     9 -    10 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 RECORDED_MINUTE                Col:    11 -    12 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 RECORDED_SECOND                Col:    13 -    14 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 SHOTLINE_NUMBER                Col:    18 -    21 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 SHOT_POINT_NO                  Col:    22 -    25 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 RECEIVERLINE_NUMBER            Col:    26 -    29 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 FIELD_STATION_NUMBER           Col:    30 -    33 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 XREC                           Col:    35 -    45 Decs:   2 Mult: 1.000000  
 YREC                           Col:    46 -    56 Decs:   2 Mult: 1.000000  
 ELEV_REC                       Col:    57 -    62 Decs:   2 Mult: 1.000000  
 XSHOT                          Col:    63 -    73 Decs:   2 Mult: 1.000000  
 YSHOT                          Col:    74 -    84 Decs:   2 Mult: 1.000000  
 ELEV_SHOT                      Col:    85 -    90 Decs:   2 Mult: 1.000000  
 TRCHDR3_TILTERROR              Col:    91 -    92 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 TRCHDR3_RESISTERROR            Col:    93 -    94 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 TRCHDR5_LEAKAGEERROR           Col:    95 -    96 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 FIELD_RECORD_NO                Col:    97 -   102 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 EXTHDR_SWATHID                 Col:   103 -   106 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 DATA_RMSAMPLITUDE              Col:   109 -   119 Decs:   8 Mult: 10000.000000  
 VWUSER_1                       Col:   121 -   125 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 CHANNEL_NO                     Col:   127 -   137 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 VWUSER_7                       Col:   140 -   142 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 VWUSER_8                       Col:   144 -   146 Decs:   1 Mult: 1.000000  
 DATA_MAXFREQ                   Col:   148 -   154 Decs:   3 Mult: 1.000000  
 DATA_MAXABSAMPLITUDE           Col:   156 -   166 Decs:   4 Mult: 10000.000000  
 VWUSER_22                      Col:   168 -   175 Decs:   3 Mult: 1.000000  
 VWUSER_11                      Col:   177 -   181 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
 VWUSER_12                      Col:   183 -   187 Decs:   0 Mult: 1.000000  
  18 327113458   5090115210965074     0.00       0.00   0.00      0.00       0.00   0.00   0 0 0    12   1  57.74633959     1           1    0 1.0 13.645  3703.4148   0.008        1     1 
  18 327113458   5090115210965075     0.00       0.00   0.00      0.00       0.00   0.00   0 0 0    12   1  35.32746807     1           2    0 1.0 18.519  3493.8994   0.008        1     1            
  18 327113458   5090115210965076     0.00       0.00   0.00      0.00       0.00   0.00   0 0 0    12   1  86.58912033     1           3    0 1.0 22.904  4077.5797   0.008        1     1            
  18 327113458   5090115210965077     0.00       0.00   0.00      0.00       0.00   0.00   0 0 0    12   1  53.32520232     1           4    0 1.0 23.392  5024.1262   0.008        1     1            
  18 327113458   5090115210965078     0.00       0.00   0.00      0.00       0.00   0.00   0 0 0    12   1  87.56771684     1           5    0 1.0 22.417  6922.9585   0.008        1     1
```

Comment: Can you share the table(s) that you need this data to be inserted into?  And try to explain how this data relates to your table(s)

Comment: If you have pro version of sql server you can use SSIS to land the file. Alternatively you can also use BULK INSERT . Dont think I need to see your file table but you sure will need a create table script to have the table ready for DML op.

Comment: Depends on how you want the data to look in the table.   If you want the whole file in one tuple, it's pretty easy, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like fixed length data.  You can try the following Bulk Insert and then parse the results into a table using Substring()

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(
  RowVal VarChar(Max)
)

BULK INSERT #tempTable
FROM 'c:\Downloads\Fixedtxt.txt' 
WITH 
(
    FIRSTROW = 31,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

SELECT * FROM #tempTable
```

Here's some parsing from what appears to be a structured portion of your text file representing your data.

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(
  RowVal VarChar(Max)
)

BULK INSERT #tempTable
FROM 'c:\Downloads\Fixedtxt.txt' 
WITH 
(
    FIRSTROW = 31,
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

SELECT 
   SubString(RowVal,1,5) As f01, 
   SubString(RowVal,6,9) As f02, 
   SubString(RowVal,18,16) As f03, 
   SubString(RowVal,35,8) As f04, 
   SubString(RowVal,44,10) As f05, 
   SubString(RowVal,55,6) As f06, 
   SubString(RowVal,62,9) As f07, 
   SubString(RowVal,72,10) As f08, 
   SubString(RowVal,83,6) As f09, 
   SubString(RowVal,90,3) As f10, 
   SubString(RowVal,94,1) As f11, 
   SubString(RowVal,96,1) As f12, 
   SubString(RowVal,98,5) As f13, 
   SubString(RowVal,104,3) As f14, 
   SubString(RowVal,108,12) As f15, 
   SubString(RowVal,121,5) As f16, 
   SubString(RowVal,127,11) As f17, 
   SubString(RowVal,139,4) As f18, 
   SubString(RowVal,144,3) As f19, 
   SubString(RowVal,148,6) As f20, 
   SubString(RowVal,155,10) As f21, 
   SubString(RowVal,166,7) As f22, 
   SubString(RowVal,174,8) As f23, 
   SubString(RowVal,183,5) As f24 
FROM 
   #tempTable
```

Results:

```
f01 f02 f03 f04 f05 f06 f07 f08 f09 f10 f11 f12 f13 f14 f15 f16 f17 f18 f19 f20 f21 f22 f23 f24
  18    327113458   5090115210965074        0.00          0.00    0.00       0.00         0.00    0.00    0 0   0      12     1  57.74633959        1             1    0    1.0 13.645   3703.4148    0.008        1        1
  18    327113458   5090115210965075        0.00          0.00    0.00       0.00         0.00    0.00    0 0   0      12     1  35.32746807        1             2    0    1.0 18.519   3493.8994    0.008        1        1
  18    327113458   5090115210965076        0.00          0.00    0.00       0.00         0.00    0.00    0 0   0      12     1  86.58912033        1             3    0    1.0 22.904   4077.5797    0.008        1        1
  18    327113458   5090115210965077        0.00          0.00    0.00       0.00         0.00    0.00    0 0   0      12     1  53.32520232        1             4    0    1.0 23.392   5024.1262    0.008        1        1
  18    327113458   5090115210965078        0.00          0.00    0.00       0.00         0.00    0.00    0 0   0      12     1  87.56771684        1             5    0    1.0 22.417   6922.9585    0.008        1        1
```

Comment: I have already tried it, this file have 30 columns and between the columns have a space caractere, the problem is that the amount of spaces changes for each column.

Comment: I added some parsing in my example.  From eyeballing quickly, I found and parsed out 24 columns.  If you know the specs or have different sample data showing the deviation from this structure that would help me.